# The type or namespace name 'ZXing' could not be found

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, zxing

In Visual Studio 2017 I have a barebones Xamarin.Forms project that I want to use to test scanning barcodes with ZXing.  I've added FastAndroidCamera, ZXing.Net.Mobile, and ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms Nuget packeages. Whenever I add any reference to ZXing in my Android project MainActivity class I get this error:

```
> The type or namespace name 'ZXing' could not be found (are you missing
> a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I get the error even if the only reference to it is

```
using ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms;
```

This will run on the emulator without error but as soon as I try to use LivePlayer to run in on my phone or tablet It fails and the above message  is displayed in the VS error list.

I've tried the Getting started info on https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/zxing.net.mobile.forms without any success.  I've also tried to use the official ZXing sample solutions on github but there are so many errors when I try to load the solution in VS2017 that it hasn't helped.

Is there something You need to do besides Adding the Nuget package to the project refences and adding a "using" statement?

Comment: Cleaning the solution and rebuilding usually helps. Restarting VS helps aswell

Comment: Thank you.  I've tried that quite a few times and the problem persists.

Comment: Have you done all the setups ? Initializing in `MainActivity` and adding permissions to `Manifest`

Comment: Let me see if I can make it work in my solution

Comment: I should also mention that the intellisense works fine for ZXing classes even though this error appears every time I try to run it on a device using live player.

Comment: What are you trying to do btw ?

Comment: Our app needs to be able to read bar codes and I wanted to familiarize myself with ZXing and understand how to use it.  I start with the simplest Xamarin forms cross-platform app generated by VS, add a button, and add the ZXing references to the  Android project.  At first I put in all the recommended code to initialize and read a bar code.  That failed so I've been creating simpler projects to figure out where the problem is.  Now I'm down to the generated project with the only added things being the ZXing references and a single using ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms; statement in MainActivity.cs

Comment: Have you made the Target.Framework 2.3 ?

Comment: The Target Framework for the PCL project is ".NET Standard 2.0" and the Android Target Framework is "8.0 Oreo".  I think 2.0 is the highest .Net Standard.

Comment: see the github page under Android versions

Comment: Just realized you probably meant the ZXing version..  It is 2.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a solution to the problem with Live Player in Visual Studio 2017, but it is a work around.  When I deploy directly to my Android device this runs without error.  People keep warning me against using android emulators and I guess the same applies to Live Player.
The moral of the story is that if an app doesn't work on an android emulator or in Live Player it might not be the fault of the app...try it on a real device.